# Iterating through database objects and rendering them to the template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have some data that I am trying to make available to a template. This is a snippet of the view attempting to do that:

```
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        beac_data = user.get_profile().owned_beacons.all()
        for beacon in beac_data:
            beacon_data_name = beacon.name
            beacon_data_factory_id = beacon.factory_id
            beacon_data_location = beacon.location
            beacon_data_visible = beacon.visible
            beacon_data_config_id = beacon.config_id
        #more code here

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'form': self.form, 
            'location': location, 
            'beacon_data_name': beacon_data_name,
            'beacon_data_factory_id': beacon_data_factory_id,
            'beacon_data_location': beacon_data_location,
            'beacon_data_visible': beacon_data_visible,
            'beacon_data_config_id': beacon_data_config_id,
        })
```

As shown, I iterate through the objects in the database and provide the relevant template tags in my html file:

```
           {{ beacon_data_name }}
           {{ beacon_data_factory_id }}
           {{ beacon_data_location }}
           {{ beacon_data_visible }}
           {{ beacon_data_config_id }}
```

The template tag works, but it only renders the information for the first object. Why isn't it returning all data for all the objects in the database? Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `beac_data` in the context and iterate through it in the template:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    beac_data = user.get_profile().owned_beacons.all()

    return render(request, self.template_name, {
        'form': self.form, 
        'location': location, 
        'beac_data': beac_data
    })
```

Then, in the template:

```
{% for beacon in beac_date %}
    {{ beacon.name }}
    {{ beacon.factory_id }}
    {{ beacon.location }}
    {{ beacon.visible }}
    {{ beacon.config_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @alexce's solution is correct, but just to explain what's happening: the problem is that when you iterate through `beac_data` in your for loop, you're storing the data into the same set of variables.  Every iteration of the loop you are *overwriting* the previous value -- so `beacon_data_name`, for example, is overwritten every time the loop runs and will only store the last iteration of beacon.name.  The solution above is probably the best way to deal with this issue.